# AngularFire2 Version 4 errors

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have been following the following tutorial : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_jxEC0hWcA

Now all the tutorials that I tried uses the older version of AngularFire2, this tutorial however had a link, which if followed would solve all problems. And that link is : https://coursetro.com/posts/code/54/Angular-4-Firebase-Tutorial:-Make-a-Simple-Angular-4-App

But the problem is this does not tell us what to do with the other stuff, it just talks about app.component.ts and app.module.ts.

What about the other places where AuthProviders, AuthMethods are used?

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';   //HostBinding is for router animations

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {  AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

//import { moveIn } from '../router.animations'; //for animations - this doesn't exist as of yet

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  //animations: [moveIn()],          //for animation
  //host: {'[@moveIn]': ''}         //for animation
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  error: any;
constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth,private router: Router) {

  this.af._subscribe(auth => { 
  if(auth) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/members');
  }
});
}

  loginFb() {
this.af.login({
  provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
  method: AuthMethods.Popup,
}).then(
    (success) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/members']);
  }).catch(
    (err) => {
    this.error = err;
  })
  }

  loginGoogle() {
this.af._login({
  provider: AuthProviders.Google,
  method: AuthMethods.Popup,
}).then(
    (success) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/members']);
  }).catch(
    (err) => {
    this.error = err;
  })
  }
 ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

This is my code for one component. What changes do I do in this to get it working?

Any help would greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, change the `AngularFire` to `AngularFireAuth` like this:

```
 constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth,private router: Router) {...}
```

Additionally, you also need to update your `loginFb()`. You don't need the `auth` after the `this.af`

```
loginFb() {
this.af.login({
  provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
  method: AuthMethods.Popup,
}).then(
    (success) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/members']);
  }).catch(
    (err) => {
    this.error = err;
  })
  }
```

Do this as well in your `loginGoogle()`

Make sure that you imported the `AuthProviders` and `AuthMethods` from 'angularfire2'.

```
import {  AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
```

Comment: And could you also please tell me about what to do with `provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
  method: AuthMethods.Popup,` because this is generating errors and on doing what you said I got 2 more, saying `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Auth'.` and `Property 'login' does not exist on type 'Auth'.`

Comment: I did what your update said but still getting the same following errors: `Cannot find name 'AuthMethods'.` `Property 'login' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.` `Cannot find name 'AuthProviders'.`

Comment: My bad, I thought you already imported it. I'll update my answer

Comment: Yeah now those AuthMethods and Providers errors are gone. Thanks. But `'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'` `'login' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.` these remain.

Comment: Can you elaborate more the error? You can try read the api docs for reference https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md

Comment: The error is that it says properties login and subscribe do not exist in AngularFireAuth

Comment: Did you update the loginGoogle() as well? Based from the code you provided, there's only two instance of the word 'login' and that's in your loginGoogle and loginFb

Comment: I have updated my code according to what you have said. You can see it now.

Comment: @SteveDoson can you double check this ? this.af._login... in your loginGoogle()

Comment: Did you remove the underscore?

Comment: Yes I did. For all of them. I tried by keeping for all as well, but that didn't help.

Comment: Your error must be something basic. You need to do some debugging yourself. Try to remove the code inside your constructor with 'subscribe'